# Can the log likelihood ratio for a simple vs simple hypothesis take a negative value?

Tags: likelihood-ratio

Can the log  likelihood ratio for a simple vs simple hypothesis take a negative value? Since it approximately follows a chi-square distribution for large sample sizes and since a chi-square distribution takes only positive values do we reject or accept the null hypothesis if a negative value is obtained for the log likelihood ratio test under a particular simple vs simple hypothesis?

The log likelihood ratio test statistic in this case is
$$-2Log\Lambda$$

Comment: Please fix your question; in this state it makes no sense.

Comment: well I've tried to fix it .. hope it makes sense in this form :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the log likelihood ratio *must* take on both positive and negative values.  If $\log \frac{f_1(x)}{f_0(x)}$ were positive for *all* possible values of the observed data $x$, then it would be true that $f_1(x) > f_0(x)$ for all $x$, 
and this is impossible.  Remember that $f_1(x)$ and $f_0(x)$ are the
probability density functions (or probability mass functions)
of the observations under the two hypotheses,
and if $f_1(x) > f_0(x)$ were to hold for all $x$, then it would be true that
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_1(x)\,\mathrm dx > \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_0(x)\,\mathrm dx$$ in contradiction of the fact that the integrals displayed
above must both equal $1$.  A similar argument applies (with sums instead
of integrals) for probability mass functions.